# How to wait for all tasks completion in VS Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio

I have a workflow which create some number of tasks to different users. These tasks are created in web service method which invoked by workflow. It can create a different amount of tasks.

I need to implement logic which will be waiting for all task completion and then change a status of current item.

*How can I implement such logic in VS?*

Web service responces array with all tasks IDs. So I have a `Collection<int>` with all IDs.
I think here I could use Parallel activity, but I don't know how.

It should be a custom approval workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented new method in the service for checking the status of all these tasks.
In the workflow I've used Delay and HttpSend activities in While Activity for checking tasks status on timer.

So the main logic implemented in web service and the workflow invokes needed methods from the service in the right order.

In such way I also simplified the process of updating logic for running workflow on production.